# What’s up with all the DV?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

However it seems that every post I write every answer I contribute gets quickly DV and my Q put on hold.

I didn’t contribute till a few days ago, and had 100 by association, I if read my page correctly day one -8 and a hold, day two – 16 and another hold, today noon -8 but the day is still early and a heavily edited Q is still on hold.

I can understand people not responding well to my Q, but I though my answers contributed and brought a different point of view.

**EDIT** - Strongly Edited my Q&A, trying to be nice-ER. I do  feel they have lost some gist and spirit in an effort to be more objective, concise, and mainstream.

Comment: i want to **thank you all** for the various answers, when i posted this on meta i was half expecting nobody responding, being DV and the Q closed.

Comment: I do think some of your existing answers could be edited to be more positive and more directly focused on the question and would probably get upvotes instead.

Comment: And for that matter, I think [Is Film photography making a comeback?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/82689/is-film-photography-making-a-comeback) is worth reopening after the edit you already made. I see that not everyone agrees with me, though.

Answer (score 8):

I think some of the downvotes on your questions may be due to the amount of information presented in your questions as fact that is incorrect. Most of those false assumptions could have been avoided by searching for and reading existing questions and answers on the subject before asking your question.

Additionally you seem to often present opinions that aren't widely held as fact. Much of that seems to also be 20 years out of date and an opinion that was in the minority even then.

Comment: This, and then combined with attacks on other posters: "naïve, misinformed Q without any research or though on the subject". Please remember that [be nice](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) is one of the core policies on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 8):

I downvoted [your answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/82740/11924) to [What's a concise "I'm not dangerous" phrase for a business card?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/14932/11924). I was put off by the combination of 2 things: the sarcastic tone at the beginning, and what I felt was poor general advice for the rest of it. Either element alone normally doesn't get a downvote from me. We have plenty of answers with a sarcastic or snarky quip, but those are usually followed up with a more light-hearted, or knowing/winking "I'm being rough, but let me clarify..." type of full explanation. And there are a lot of answers that I disagree with the advice given, but not enough to downvote (it's more of a "meh" response from me).

So to me, your answer came across as slightly dismissively sarcastic, with advice that I feel doesn't help the photography community as a whole, or photographers individually. Combined, those factors almost met my downvote threshold. I "rounded up" to the threshold because I wanted to discourage that answer and that type of answer.

---

On the subject of the questions you've asked, I didn't downvote any of them. Personally, I think they are interesting *conversations* or debates. But they are particularly poor questions **for the Stack Exchange Q&A format**, so I voted to close them. They are fine forum discussions, but Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum.

From this site's help center, [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)
>
> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

The questions you've asked fall into these categories, in my opinion.

---

Like I said, in a *different context* (meaning *forum*, not a Q&A site), I like your questions and the discussions they would probably generate. It's clear you have a lot of experience, and I think you probably have some great answers in you just itching to come out. I hope you stick around — I'm looking forward to seeing them.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't downvote, but I specifically didn't upvote on a [post](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/39501/why-do-some-photographers-cover-up-the-brand-name-on-their-camera/82726#82726) where you refer to "the 'poor bugger' in a 3d world country". I'm not clear on what *exactly* you mean, but it seems disparaging, and that's not the kind of attitude I want to see in posts on this site. You have [another answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/whats-a-concise-im-not-dangerous-phrase-for-a-business-card/82740#82740) (about a "harmless identifier" on a business card) where I literally cannot tell where the sarcasm ends and the serious answer begins, if it ever does at all — it just seems to blend into a rant about "the general public". And your "what is the point of AF" [question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/whats-a-concise-im-not-dangerous-phrase-for-a-business-card/82740#82740) *also* seemed more like a somewhat-strange aggressive rant than an attempt to actually learn or help anyone.

If you want upvotes, maybe... less nastiness, more helpfulness?

Comment: Thanks will try to do beter, BTW the "poor bugger" was in reference to another answer; i know that 3d world is not "politicaly correct", but i was born in a 3d world country and live in one now, so i feel that gives me the right to use 3d world country instead of the meeker and often inacurate "developing country". i also traveled all over the world in very poor countries and i think i understand how they perceive tourists with expensive gear.

Comment: @Reed Since you used quotes, I did first look to see if another answer used that term, but none do.

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at some of your questions and answers. I can't speak to specifics, and I think that you're not going to get an answer there anyways, but from a more general perspective I think your challenge has been "opinion" is a factor in both your questions and answers, rather than facts. Opinions generate discussion, which is cool for chat rooms and discussion boards, but less so for a site like this and this site tends to make that known rapidly.

It's not to say, by the way, that opinion can't play a role, but that opinion should be backed up by some additional insight or information that shows justification for it.

Comment: thanks, for clarifying, i'll try to be more carefull

Comment: @Reed - No prob. Don't be discouraged, this is a tough crowd! Just bear in mind that if you're asking for, or giving, speculative responses, you'll probably trip the down vote and close cycle.